# Change "Chat" word in discussion module

Tags: chat, iccube-reporting

In the last releases of iccube reporting, in the discussion new module, "Chat" is written by default.
Is there a way to change this text ?
In my case, I just want to make it more "french".

[image]

Comment: Which translation would you like: e.g., "Conversations" ?

Comment: Yes, sounds good, Txs Marc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in latest version of the reporting; waiting for you input in the comment section of the question, the default French value will be "Discussions".

Hope that helps.